# GitHub organization filter repositories by non-archived

Tags: github

Our GitHub organization has an approximate ratio of 5:1 archived to non-archived repositories making finding active (i.e. non-archived) repositories hard.

How can the repositories of an organization be filtered to non-archived repositories to make navigation manageable?

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `archived:false` filter in the search field.

Or add it to the URL as a GET parameter, if you need to link it somewhere else.
`https://github.com/orgs/%org-name%/repositories?q=archived:false`

Source: [GitHub Docs](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/#search-based-on-whether-a-repository-is-archived)